# How to get the file type value and append the file type along with the value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file-upload

I have one button on my page called `Add more fields`. When the user clicks on the button then the bootstrap modal will open with the label name and file upload fields. The user can add the label name and file.

The user can add multiple times. Whatever the user adding in the label name and file upload that I am displaying on the page using jQuery append.

Now, my issue is, I am able to append the data correctly but I am not getting the file name that the user uploaded.

Once I get the label name and file then I have inserted the data into the database.

I know there is some issue with my script. What can I do to resolve it?

[image]

```js
$(".clicktoaddfile").click(function() {

  var labelname = $('#labelname').val();
  var filename=$("#newfileuploaded")[0].files[0]['name'];
  var html = '<div class="col-lg-3"><label>' + labelname + '<label><div class=""><input type="file" value=' + filename + '></div></div>';
  $('#appendhere').append(html);

  $('#labelname').val('');
  $('#newfileuploaded').val('');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>
  <div class="row" id="appendhere"></div>
  <input type="submit" name="">
</form>


<div class="w-100 text-center pt-3 pb-4">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addcustomDoc" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-customDoc">+ Add Custom Document</a>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="modal-customDoc" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Document Upload</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group mt-4">
          <label for="labelname" class="form-label">Type of Document</label>
          <input type="text" name="labelname" class="form-control" id="labelname" placeholder="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-4">
          <div class="documentUploadWrap">
            <div class="upload_doc">
              <div class="closefile"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close_img"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></div>
              <input type="file" name="uploadfile[]" class="fileupload" id="newfileuploaded">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn themeBg clicktoaddfile">Add Document</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```